# Live score android application

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I am in the process of developing an android application for live score and statistics. Assume that I have an XML feed which updates every second and the file size is around 400KB. But I need only specific content from the XML file. Polling the XML file at regular interval and parsing it seems to be time consuming task.

What is the best method to implement a live score application?

Will it be a good idea to implement a web service that polls only the required part of the XML feed and respond the client with the parsed data?